# Problem switching between portrait mode and landscape mode for a table

Tags: uitableview, rotation, landscape

I have a UIViewController that inherits all the delegation for the UITable. 
I have a UITableView called table that is set in my simple_tableViewController.h.

I have set

`- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

  return YES;
 }`

but the main view rotates but the table does not.

I have been searching for over a few hours now to find out how to implement the rotation from portrait to landscape for my UITableView inside my UIViewController.

Here is some code

```
@interface simple_tableViewController : UIViewController 
 
{
 UITableView *table;
 UISearchBar *search;
 NSDictionary *allNames;
 NSMutableDictionary *allNamesSearch;
 NSMutableDictionary *names;
 NSMutableArray *keys;
 BOOL isSearching;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *allNames;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *allNamesSearch;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *names;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *keys;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *keysSearch;
- (void)resetSearch;
- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm;

@end
```

You can see where I create the UITableView.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it was because I was adding the view to the main window view. So the main window view was rotating but the navigation controller view was not.

Hope that helps someone out.

Thanks